# how to call vue.js method in in side template tag and show method return data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm developing web application using laravel and Vue.js,and i'm new to the these frameworks.
now i need to call method inside vue component and show it return data ,in side the v-for loop
i try several ways but can;t get proper way to my requirement

my IsAvaiabaleRefund() work like this,

when component crate stage load data and show its in the table,then it when load it call IsAvaiabaleRefund() function and pass invoice data and return it and showing table,so i can be call in the create faction

here i put my component code

```html
              <tbody>
                <tr div v-for="invoices in invoice">
                  <th scope="row">{{invoices.p_id}}</th>
                  <td>{{invoices.p_amount}}</td>
                  <td>{{invoices.p_qty}}</td>      
                  <td>{{invoices.p_amount}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <!-- here i need call method and and print its data:  -->
                    {{IsAvaiabaleRefund(invoices.p_id,'002') }}         
                  </td> 
                </tr>             
              </tbody>
```

this is my script

```js
    export default{        

        data(){
            return {
                invoice:{},         
            }
        },

        methods:{

          IsAvaiabaleRefund(p_id,incoice_id){    // <----
            axios.get('/check-refund-data/'+p_id+'/'+incoice_id)
           .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.refund = response.data;      
           })
          }
        },

        created(){
            axios.get('/refund-data/002').then(response => {
            this.invoice = response.data.invoice
            console.log(response.data.invoice);     
            })

            .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }
```

any one have some way to solve this please suggest me ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pull data in your Vue component, you do that on the beginning of the Vue instance life cycle (onCreate, created, mounted, etc.) Then you *change* an attribute (key in `data`) of the instance that *already exists* since the initiation of the instance.

```html
              <tbody>
                <tr div v-for="invoices in invoice">
                  <th scope="row">{{invoices.p_id}}</th>
                  <td>{{invoices.p_amount}}</td>
                  <td>{{invoices.p_qty}}</td>      
                  <td>{{invoices.p_amount}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <!-- here i need call method and and print its data:  -->
                    {{refund}}         
                  </td> 
                </tr>             
              </tbody>
```

script

```js
    export default{        

        data(){
            return {
                invoice:{},
                refund: "" // data not pulled yet
            }
        },

        methods:{

          IsAvaiabaleRefund(p_id,incoice_id){
            axios.get('/check-refund-data/'+p_id+'/'+incoice_id)
           .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.refund = response.data;      
           })
          }
        },

        created(){


            axios.get('/refund-data/002').then(response => {
            this.invoice = response.data.invoice
            console.log(response.data.invoice);
            IsAvaiabaleRefund(invoices.p_id,'002')
            })

            .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion,but its not working beacuse cant pass invoice id one by one ..